# regexp php - negate 4 digit (year ) number

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to separate and get a number out of a string that contains 2 similar HTML statements:

1 - `<td class="center"><p class="texte">1914</p></td>`

2 - `<td class="center"><p class="texte">135.000</p></td>`

So, I am looking for the number 135.000 and not the number 1914.

IMPORTANT: This is not US notation for number. 135.000 is actually one hundred and thirty five thousands.

I have tried things like `([1-9][0-9]{1,2})`, but that will capture `191` out of statement 1 above, which is not intended.

Thanks

Comment: As Don't Panic says. `([1-9][0-9]{1,2}\.\d+)`. But that means you use regex on html.

Comment: Can you provide a more specific use case? All 4 digit numbers are invalid? You only want numbers with decimals?

Comment: @chris85. In statement 2 I would have numbers from zero to 999.999. So, there will always be a decimal point over 999. The other field is year, which means always 4 digits and no decimal point.

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/xQ9cO5/1?

Comment: @chris85. That actually seems to work. Can you please put that as an answer and comment on it. Thanks.

Comment: Would a 5 digit integer without a full stop ever be valid? I have a feeling this is going to fail in some instances, but with the limited tests I can't find the occurrence yet. `^\d{4,}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$` Here's an article on this regex approach http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html.

Comment: I'd use `(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?!\d)`, but the edge cases are too many.

Comment: @chris85. No. On statement 2, whenever it goes over 999 a point ( or thousands ) separator will be required.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Thanks, but regex101.com did not like your expression and is throwing an error.

Comment: Oh, [`(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/xQ9cO5/2) works well at regex101. It depends on what flavor you select. It won't work in JS since JS regex does not support lookbehinds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. You are right! I had js selected. Your solution actually seems to work us does chris85's. Not sure what the difference is. Waiting for you guys to put it up as an answer and further checking it in the meantime. Thanks.

Comment: The difference is huge (for regexes): chris' pattern matches `135.00066666`, mine will just match `135`. If these numbers are to be ignored as a whole, use `(?<!\d\.|\d)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?!\.?\d)`. As I mentioned, there are too many edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with html, you need to use an html parser first (XPATH is your friend). Then you need the `preg_match` function to filter numbers with your desired format. Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourHtmlString);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

// you need to register the function `preg_match` to use it in your xpath query
$xp->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xp->registerPhpFunctions('preg_match');

// The xpath query
$targetNodeList = $xp->query('//td[@class="center"]/p[@class="texte"][php:functionString("preg_match", "~^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:\.[0-9]{3})*$~", .) > 0]');
#                             ^                                     ^^                                                                             ^
#                             '------------------+------------------''-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------'
#                                                '- describe the path in the DOM tree                    |
#                                                                                                        '- predicate to check the content format  

foreach ($targetNodeList as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Give this a shot :)

```
\s*[\d.]+(?=<)
```

Here is the link:
[Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/lK4vK9/1)

Comment: The `+` in the character class is allowing multiple `+`s. Also this would allow 2016, no? (`and not the number 1914`)

Comment: @user3597719. When I added the capture group to the whole regexp, it seems to capture both situations. So, does not seem to solve it.

Comment: @BernardA oh! I misunderstood your question. Trying to solve it now

Comment: @user3597719. It still gets both numbers when I add the capture group. You can try that yourself.